# What frame is this?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

Could you help to find out the brand, type, & year model of this MTB frame?

The "Gary Fisher" decal was added later and is not correct.

[image]

Comment: I don't recognize the model, but it says Gary Fisher is the brand (now part of Trek, but bikepedia/bicycle blue book should help you track down through the few models they did.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Batman, but it just a new decal from the seller, he's not sure about it :) but thank you for your attention.

Comment: Old post, and I wasn't able to find the frame. There are some good clues though. Between the drivetrain, quill stem, fork (looks just like a Specialized steel fork), chrome seat QR with rubber bit etc,  it appears to be from around 1991. The closest I could find was the steel version of the SBike Daytona, which isn't really all that clost other than the monotube with the braces. My money would be on it being custom.